# Cakephp3: Render/Evaluate HTML inside label formhelper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How you place html inside label in cakephp3?

I need to achieve 
* Name:

using the code below

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input ( 'name', [ 
            'label' => [ 
                    'text' => '<span class="red">*</span> Name:',
                    'class' => 'col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-1 control-label' 
            ],
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'rows' => 1 
    ] );
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pretty much as always, use the [**`escape` option**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Widget.LabelWidget.html#_render).

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', [ 
    'label' => [ 
        // ...
        'escape' => false
    ],
    // ...
]);
```