# cant display superscript in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I cant display a superscript in cakephp. I have used a few methods. Do I have to include a math library and use this instead?

```
     //the below does not produce a superscript and prints as as is

    $q='12 X 8&sup2; =';
    //also tried
    $q='12 X 8<sup>2</sup> ='
    $q='12 X 8'.<sup>.'2'.</sup>.' ='
    echo $this->Form->input('a1',array('value'=>$assessment['a1'],'label'=>$q));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable escaping of the label text, because it contains html tags. This was also discussed in this question [Cakephp3: Render/Evaluate HTML inside label formhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991447/cakephp3-render-evaluate-html-inside-label-formhelper).

Instead of just adding the value, you should use the following code for `label`:

```
'label' => [
    'text' => $q,
    'escape' => false,
],
```

In total, this means:

```
$q = '12 X 8<sup>2</sup> =';
echo $this->Form->input('a1', [
    'value' => $assessment['a1'],
    'label' => [
        'text' => $q,
        'escape' => false,
    ],
]);
```